# How to setup a Jersey + Tomcat RESTful Java web app?

Tags: java, tomcat, heroku, intellij-idea, jersey

Excuse me for my lack naivety of Java Web applications, but I can't seem to understand the best way to setup my Java application.

**The Problem:**

Currently I've been building a RESTful API application locally, using Jersey & Tomcat. I setup Tomcat via Intellij and all of my endpoint methods look like this. There's no `main()` method anywhere in my application and all is working fine.

```
@GET @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response getMessage() {

    String message = "Please specify an endpoint.";

    return Response.status(200).entity(message).build();
}
```

However, I'm trying to deploy my application to Heroku. Heroku is able to build it, but when I open up the URLs I get `Application Errors` and after checking the logs, I get the obvious:

```
2015-04-07T15:58:31.407658+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/gympeak/schools" host=gympeak-api.herokuapp.com request_id=02018a23-900d-4365-84a5-a54b82c4788a fwd="152.17.156.116" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Basically telling me there's no web application running. I think part of this is because my application can launch Tomcat locally (since it's configured with Intellij), but not on Heroku. I've tried editing the ***Procfile*** to do something like this:

```
web: java -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* com._1834Software.endpoints.Index
```

But again, the problem is that it can't start anything since there's no `main()` method.

**The Question:**

How do I deploy a Java web application using Tomcat that **does not** have a `main()` method? Is this even possible? It seems to work fine locally but out in the wild, it doesn't.

I've seen people do something similar to this using Tomcat, but it doesn't make sense to me to do that when I'm able to launch Tomcat locally. http://blog.sortedset.com/embedded-tomcat-jersey/

Also, in case it helps, this is my `web.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>GymPeak API</servlet-name>

    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>GymPeak API</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may want to use `webapp-runner` to launch your WAR file. Here is an article on setting this up:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-webapp-runner

Comment: Yes, webapp-runner did the trick. Heroku was pretty explicit about this in tutorial and I overlooked it. After some struggling, this worked. Thanks.

Comment: @carbon_ghost.. could you please tell us how you solved it? a step-by-step guide would be awesome.. im stuck at the same issue..

Answer (score 0):

You can start a Tomcat instance and deploy a war with your Jersey based application on it. This way you don't need a main method, just a standard servlet app.

You can check [this project](https://github.com/pagafa/jerseyBase), that it's an example of that. It uses gradle to build the war.